# Plot a legend through ggplot using three different dependent-predictor series

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, regression

[I had previously posted where I was unable to plot a legend using one dependent variable and three different predictor variables using ggplot's geom_smooth function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684916/how-to-add-multiple-geom-smooth-lines-to-the-legend-ggplot/58710975?noredirect=1#comment103769673_58710975). I was fortunate enough to gain direction related to that issue.

I am now posed with a second dilemma; trying to create a plot with a legend which includes multiple geom_smooth lines where each trendline represents a different set of predictors ***and*** a different set of dependents. Current (legend-less) code is as follows:

```
png(filename="D:/Users/...", width = 10, height = 8, units = 'in', res = 300)
ggplot(Data) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(BAp1,BAgp1),colour="red",fill="red") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(BAp2,BAgp2),colour="turquoise",fill="turquoise") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(BAp3,BAgp3),colour="orange",fill="orange") + 
  xlab(bquote('Tree Basal Area ('~cm^2~')')) + 
  ylab(bquote('Predicted Basal Area Growth ('~cm^2~')')) + 
  labs(title = expression(paste("Other Softwoods")), subtitle = "Tree Level Basal Area Growth") +
  theme_bw()
dev.off()
```

[image: current plot]

The previous solution, which employed the pivot_longer function, would only be effective where the same dependent is used within all three regressions and therefore can't be applied here.

**EDIT**

I've now provided a sampling of the dataset used in the plot above:

```
YEAR,SPC,BA,BAg,BAs,BAp1,BAgp1,BAp2,BAgp2,BAp3,BAgp3,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,203.58307,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,292.55294,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,320.47389,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,271.71636,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,120.76281,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,191.13451,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,251.64941,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,323.6547,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,479.1636,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,221.67076,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,314.15927,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,143.13882,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,91.60885,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,235.0618,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,128.67964,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,116.89866,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,240.52819,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,181.45839,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,76.97687,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,147.41138,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,103.86891,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,181.45839,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,160.60607,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,132.73229,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,153.93804,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,339.79464,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,56.74502,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,162.86015,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,151.74677,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,111.22023,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,235.0618,NA,0.002070873,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,229.65829,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,229.65829,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,502.72548,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,615.75216,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,109.35884,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,289.5292,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,151.74677,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,430.0526,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,198.5565,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,156.14502,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,251.64941,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,213.82465,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,359.68093,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,295.59244,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,2.2698,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,143.13882,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,352.98938,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,198.5565,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,411.87064,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,147.41138,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,213.82465,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,96.76891,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,366.43538,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,254.469,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,229.65829,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,494.80871,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,555.71634,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,383.59633,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,274.64591,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,162.86015,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,263.02197,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,183.85386,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,369.83617,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,107.51315,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,419.09633,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,122.71846,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,283.52874,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,683.49275,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,289.5292,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,359.68093,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,132.73229,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,510.70516,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,151.74677,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,165.12996,NA,0.003241326,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,38.48451,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,84.94866,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,15.20531,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,65.03883,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,105.68318,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,21.23716,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,95.03318,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,43.0084,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,51.52998,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,56.74502,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,105.68318,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,19.63495,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,9.62113,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,8.55299,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,130.6981,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,96.76891,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,103.86891,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,93.31315,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,203.58307,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,67.92909,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,47.78363,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,5.72555,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,62.21138,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,196.0668,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,9.0792,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,38.48451,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,3.46361,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,98.52034,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,111.22023,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,138.92909,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,132.73229,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,52.81017,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,78.53982,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,23.75829,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,17.34944,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,96.76891,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,78.53982,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,124.68982,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,8.04248,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,72.3823,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,107.51315,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,103.86891,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,86.59015,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,65.03883,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,34.21194,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,3.80133,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,138.92909,NA,0.001999849,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,160.60607,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,134.78219,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,128.67964,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,91.60885,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,84.94866,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,96.76891,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,51.52998,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,100.28749,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,156.14502,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,186.26502,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,156.14502,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,153.93804,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,172.03362,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,76.97687,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,169.71668,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,58.08805,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,122.71846,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,51.52998,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,132.73229,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,203.58307,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,51.52998,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,80.11847,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,66.4761,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,59.44678,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,66.4761,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,124.68982,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,128.67964,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,111.22023,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,69.39778,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,118.82289,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,100.28749,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,51.52998,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,70.88218,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,118.82289,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,72.3823,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,78.53982,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,78.53982,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,89.92023,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,151.74677,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2010,GS,193.59279,NA,0.002976025,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,19.63495,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,25.51758,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,38.48451,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,25.51758,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,63.61725,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,15.90431,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,7.06858,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,27.33971,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,19.63495,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,11.94591,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,98.52034,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,15.20531,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,19.63495,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,21.23716,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,15.90431,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,8.55299,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,35.25652,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,10.17876,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,24.63009,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,32.16991,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,27.33971,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,22.06184,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,15.20531,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,31.17245,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,19.63495,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,16.61902,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,22.90221,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,20.42821,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,7.06858,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,41.85387,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,18.85741,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,51.52998,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,51.52998,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,69.39778,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,16.61902,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,18.09558,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,37.39281,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,51.52998,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,75.42964,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,43.0084,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,47.78363,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,45.3646,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,44.17865,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,16.61902,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,18.85741,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,80.11847,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,20.42821,NA,0.001146144,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,65.03883,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,56.74502,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,301.71857,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,100.28749,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,196.0668,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,158.36768,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,128.67964,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,346.36059,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,172.03362,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,52.81017,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,45.3646,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,17.34944,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,20.42821,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,186.26502,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,65.03883,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,116.89866,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,65.03883,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,30.1907,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,240.52819,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,198.5565,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,109.35884,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,80.11847,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,40.71504,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,216.42433,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,80.11847,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,198.5565,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,84.94866,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,201.06193,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,251.64941,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,122.71846,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,208.67242,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,145.26725,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,232.35221,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,91.60885,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,138.92909,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,188.69191,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,86.59015,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,156.14502,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,37.39281,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,193.59279,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,289.5292,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,113.09734,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,31.17245,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,165.12996,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,44.17865,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,172.03362,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2011,GS,186.26502,NA,0.0072219,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,21.23716,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,6.6052,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,2.83529,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,8.04248,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,32.16991,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,7.06858,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,24.63009,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,4.90874,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,22.06184,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,6.15752,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,22.06184,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,9.62113,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,4.52389,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,4.15476,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,13.20254,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,2.83529,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,19.63495,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,30.1907,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,13.85442,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,9.0792,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,11.94591,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,12.56637,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,19.63495,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,0.785398,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,13.20254,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,5.30929,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,12.56637,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,8.04248,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,6.15752,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,22.90221,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,2.2698,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,2.2698,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,2.2698,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,10.7521,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,2.83529,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,0.502655,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,12.56637,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,31.17245,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,15.20531,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,3.46361,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,14.52201,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,11.34115,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,13.20254,NA,0.000270151,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,22.90221,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,15.20531,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,10.17876,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,1.13097,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,1.32732,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,31.17245,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,37.39281,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,7.54768,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,32.16991,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,33.18307,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,40.71504,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,10.17876,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,12.56637,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,13.20254,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,20.42821,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,5.72555,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,18.09558,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,11.94591,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,3.46361,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,56.74502,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,8.04248,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,6.15752,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,11.94591,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,4.90874,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,11.94591,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,33.18307,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,7.54768,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,1.53938,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,1.32732,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,2.83529,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,13.20254,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,9.62113,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,9.0792,NA,0.000615944,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,5.72555,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2003,GS,138.92909,13.0847344,0.003090766,39.66762,4.5739326,113.00754,4.6844832,146.22059,7.29150748,,,,,,,,,,
2008,GS,191.13451,10.44108426,0.0042038,64.18895,6.1426749,136.55422,4.4894855,172.93962,3.02896885,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,219.03971,6.97630185,0.004530738,84.26219,6.812149,155.42866,4.50066,186.73834,2.38524049,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,4.15476,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,6.15752,0.50069132,0.000749127,13.13855,2.8423224,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,7.06858,0.22776552,0.001892294,27.66004,4.1044984,8.18703,1.1184496,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,4.52389,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,35.25652,7.68315694,0.000749127,13.72853,2.9012578,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,111.22023,18.99092631,0.001892294,28.50867,4.1791816,118.33232,7.1120902,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2003,GS,198.5565,21.83406834,0.003090766,46.02372,5.1020081,143.4212,5.8313954,208.2341,9.67759599,,,,,,,,,,
2008,GS,268.80252,14.04920425,0.0042038,73.47428,6.9080746,172.93508,5.6709952,249.09621,5.26243503,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,301.71857,8.22901219,0.004530738,96.45316,7.7556394,199.6002,6.3364367,272.37363,3.97850066,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,6.15752,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,45.3646,9.80176885,0.000749127,16.27949,3.136689,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,107.51315,15.53713858,0.001892294,32.10894,4.4623873,115.66877,8.1556236,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2003,GS,183.85386,19.08517739,0.003090766,50.94628,5.4811665,141.13239,5.764764,193.33334,9.47947965,,,,,,,,,,
2008,GS,254.469,14.12302886,0.0042038,80.73998,7.5382957,170.32979,5.5791972,229.21812,4.58140665,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,274.64591,5.04422531,0.004530738,105.98191,8.5122454,196.69386,6.289291,251.65457,3.88456353,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,8.55299,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,51.52998,10.74424815,0.000749127,19.92864,3.452061,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,124.68982,18.2899604,0.001892294,37.18107,4.8400702,133.76642,9.0765972,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2003,GS,198.5565,18.46667005,0.003090766,57.54763,5.9228014,163.02259,6.7293613,209.07802,10.52151769,,,,,,,,,,
2008,GS,271.71636,14.63197192,0.0042038,89.87941,8.186619,197.06897,6.5385713,251.23609,5.2890248,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,298.64765,6.73282297,0.004530738,117.66054,9.4086648,227.67492,7.2823007,274.96065,4.30888721,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,6.15752,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,37.39281,7.80882155,0.000749127,16.27949,3.136689,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,98.52034,15.28188367,0.001892294,32.10894,4.4623873,105.35308,6.8327348,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2003,GS,169.71668,17.79908562,0.003090766,50.94628,5.4811665,128.75935,5.5595442,178.05133,8.33464615,,,,,,,,,,
2008,GS,229.65829,11.9883205,0.0042038,80.73998,7.5382957,156.81984,5.3981216,209.81761,3.85660184,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,251.64941,5.4977819,0.004530738,105.98191,8.5122454,179.59762,5.4342788,228.50327,3.19001167,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,5.30929,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,33.18307,6.9684453,0.000749127,14.95397,3.0132536,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,88.24734,13.7660679,0.001892294,30.1993,4.2944465,94.23995,5.9926068,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2003,GS,149.57123,15.3309716,0.003090766,48.24276,5.2335099,114.8419,4.7214463,157.03939,7.4681619,,,,,,,,,,
2008,GS,213.82465,12.85068392,0.0042038,76.63461,7.1581349,138.51638,4.5167748,184.41302,3.12287756,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,232.35221,4.63189082,0.004530738,100.51495,8.0424901,158.24583,4.5211926,200.3679,3.02820153,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,5.72555,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,36.31681,7.64781507,0.000749127,15.60207,3.067957,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,93.31315,14.24908404,0.001892294,31.18053,4.4020865,99.99643,6.6832802,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2003,GS,156.14502,15.70796701,0.003090766,49.63783,5.3747012,121.68928,4.8377575,164.0409,7.89588074,,,,,,,,,,
2008,GS,203.58307,9.48761005,0.0042038,78.74908,7.3374128,145.96838,4.6370767,194.72718,3.74884103,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,208.67242,1.27233773,0.004530738,103.23439,8.2732858,166.21787,4.6631889,212.9025,3.08333016,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,0.636172,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,1.53938,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,16.61902,3.76991102,0.000749127,8.82182,2.4178751,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,49.0167,8.09941903,0.001892294,21.4849,3.6096224,52.59159,3.5748876,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2003,GS,78.53982,7.38077895,0.003090766,36.46379,4.3377525,66.96562,3.4858304,82.72449,4.1846743,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,7.06858,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,44.17865,9.27751581,0.000749127,17.68187,3.2593534,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,91.60885,11.85754958,0.001892294,34.09134,4.6271977,98.78823,7.1793815,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2003,GS,141.02609,12.35431029,0.003090766,53.54448,5.660999,120.30488,4.7928505,148.48802,7.46192924,,,,,,,,,,
2008,GS,162.86015,4.36681367,0.0042038,84.38349,7.808137,144.39893,4.5996242,174.95356,3.04325908,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,176.71459,3.46360806,0.004530738,110.81629,8.9793126,164.47864,4.6075064,188.82099,2.39053144,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,13.20254,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,70.88218,14.41991043,0.000749127,26.79089,4.0074362,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,147.41138,19.13229823,0.001892294,46.38589,5.4484046,158.52939,11.1180098,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2003,GS,246.05741,24.66150866,0.003090766,69.24519,6.6154131,194.1273,8.3284548,258.2328,12.17538864,,,,,,,,,,
2008,GS,280.55207,6.89893096,0.0042038,105.31282,9.0822677,233.17628,7.5382663,305.30992,6.08359541,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,298.64765,4.52389625,0.004530738,136.40607,10.5118973,268.0019,8.2514072,334.70723,5.39582561,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,3.46361,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,32.16991,7.17657604,0.000749127,12.01707,2.7297405,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,96.76891,16.14975116,0.001892294,26.02869,3.9618723,102.95209,6.183171,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
2003,GS,165.12996,17.09026237,0.003090766,42.5563,4.7945855,125.4901,5.5013052,173.26155,8.13158982,,,,,,,,,,
2008,GS,208.67242,8.70849093,0.0042038,68.28839,6.415111,152.01955,4.7109596,204.955,3.82817882,,,,,,,,,,
2012,GS,229.65829,5.24646718,0.004530738,89.53456,7.2058142,174.53924,5.3586628,223.52047,3.16490979,,,,,,,,,,
1991,GS,5.30929,NA,0.000129404,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1995,GS,39.59192,8.57065729,0.000749127,14.95397,3.0132536,NA,NA,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
1999,GS,103.86891,16.06924669,0.001892294,30.1993,4.2944465,111.37113,7.5022219,NA,NA,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Can you give us `dput(Data)` I know how to do it, but I need the example dataset

Comment: @DerekCorcoran I've now provided the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Brian Fisher suggested, you need to map to colour within `aes()` for a legend to appear automatically. Ideally you would reshape your data such that you could make a single call to `geom_smooth` but this should also suffice.

```
d <- read.csv("tmp.csv")

ggplot(d) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(BAp1,BAgp1, color = "value 1", fill = "value 1")) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(BAp2,BAgp2, color = "value 2", fill = "value 2")) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(BAp3,BAgp3, color = "value 3", fill = "value 3")) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("value 1" = "red", "value 2" = "turquoise", "value 3" = "orange"), 
    name = "Scale name",
    aesthetics = c("fill", "color")
  ) +
  xlab(bquote('Tree Basal Area ('~cm^2~')')) + 
  ylab(bquote('Predicted Basal Area Growth ('~cm^2~')')) + 
  labs(title = expression(paste("Other Softwoods")), subtitle = "Tree Level Basal Area Growth") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: the plot]

Answer (score 3):

Without example data it is more difficult to verify that something works.

That said, to get a legend in ggplot, you need to have something mapped within an aesthetic.
In your example code, moving the colour mapping into the aes(), then provide labels for the color scale:

```
ggplot(Data) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(BAp1,BAgp1,colour="red"),fill="red") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(BAp2,BAgp2,colour="turquoise"),fill="turquoise") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(BAp3,BAgp3,colour="orange"),fill="orange") + 
  xlab(bquote('Tree Basal Area ('~cm^2~')')) + 
  ylab(bquote('Predicted Basal Area Growth ('~cm^2~')')) + 
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("red","turquoise", "orange"), 
    labels = c("something", "another", "third"), 
values =  c("red","turquoise", "orange"))+
  labs(title = expression(paste("Other Softwoods")), subtitle = "Tree Level Basal Area Growth") +
  theme_bw()
```

Now you provided example data, we can suggest a method to reshape your data before plotting.  This will pay off if you are going to use the same data set for more than one plot.

```
new_d <- Data %>%
      gather(key= "group", value = "p", starts_with("BAp")) %>%
      gather(key = "group2", value = "gp", starts_with("BAg"))

# You could rename your groups at this point, or drop the second group variable.
# But at this point we can proceed with a more straight forward plotting script

ggplot(new_d)+
      geom_smooth(aes(x=p, y = gp, fill = group, color = group))+
      scale_color_manual(
            values =  c("red","turquoise", "orange"),
            aesthetics = c("fill", "color")
      )+
      xlab(bquote('Tree Basal Area ('~cm^2~')')) + 
      ylab(bquote('Predicted Basal Area Growth ('~cm^2~')')) + 
      labs(title = expression(paste("Other Softwoods")), subtitle = "Tree Level Basal Area Growth") +
      theme_bw()
```

Comment: this adds the colour of the line to a legend where I also include specify scale_colour_manual but does not, in this case, include the CI shading in the legend item. Where I also include 'fill' in the aes, the legend includes the same CI shading behind all three legend items, albeit it is correct for at least one of the three items. Data has also been added to the post.